# VBS running code from string

Tags: vbscript, hex

I have one string storing hexadecimal data (\xEA\x...). Is it anyway to run that code using vbs? Maybe doing some kind of casting to function pointer or similar.

The C version of what I'm trying to do would be:

```
unsigned char opcode[] = "\xc0\x...."
main()
{
    int (*run)() = (int(*)())opcode;
    run();
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you could show some of your code that may be helpful. Also how have you tried to run this?

Comment: I think you should try to rephrase your question. It's really hard to work out your intention here. As Keith Smiley suggested, a code example would be very helpful in explaining what it is you want to do.

Comment: You should also explain what you actually want to achieve by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function pointers (or function references) with the GetRef function:

```
dim fp : set fp = GetRef("ShowMessage")
call fp("Woosh")

function ShowMessage(msg)
    msgbox msg
end function
```

To make this work for any string with normally illegal characters for function naming (like the backslash in hexadecimal data) you can use brackets in you function declaration:

```
dim fp : set fp = GetRef("99 problems")
call fp()

' note: functions normally cannot start with a digit or contain spaces
function [99 problems]()
    msgbox "but this aint one"
end function
```

The only character you cannot use is a closing bracket: `]`